# DataDog fails on Instance#0 for statsd collection

Tags: c#, datadog

I have a C# service installed on a machine that I publish stats to a DataDogAgent (which I later monitor).  I uses StatsD as the library to publish the stats, the DataDogAgent is installed locally on the machine.  When I first set this up it worked great and no issues.

When I released new code to the box and re-installed the service I stopped getting updated stats to DataDog.  When I look in the DataDogAgent in the collection log I see

```
2016-08-18 14:26:21 Eastern Daylight Time | ERROR | checks.statsd(__init__.pyc:767) | Check 'statsd' instance #0 failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checks\__init__.pyc", line 750, in run
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Datadog\Datadog Agent\files\..\checks.d\statsd.py", line 28, in check
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Datadog\Datadog Agent\files\..\checks.d\statsd.py", line 86, in _send_command
Exception: Failed connection [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I have verified that my code that submits via StatsD has not changed and is correctly sending out the stats I want.  I also repaired, uninstalled and re-installed and restarted the DataDogAgent all with no success.  The timing is suspect to when I released code but I don't see what I would have changed that would cause this.

Everything is set to go to port 8125 for StatsD

Comment: Looks like a firewall is getting in the way... "target machine actively refused it".  StatsD uses UDP to talk to the DogStatsD Agent that is running on machine, which is a jump between processes.  Just my 2 cents....